# Combine and sort data based on indices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, indexing

I have 2 datasets like this

`dataset1` (31x1 double):

```
0
32
45
8
...
91
```

`dataset2` (40x1 double):

```
5
12
27
10
...
15
```

I also have `dataset1_index` (31x1 double) that indexes the values of `datset1` from a larger dataset

```
2
5
6
9
...
58
```

Similarly, I have `dataset2_index` (40x1 double) that indexes the values of `datset2` from the same larger dataset

```
3
7
8
13
...
62
```

I would like to combine `dataset1` and `dataset2` into `dataset3` (71x1 double) but the order of values in dataset3 should follow the order (from small to large) of `dataset1_index` and `dataset2_index`. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a 71x2 matrix containing the indices and values, then [`sortrows()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.sortrows.html) on the index column, and take the sorted values column

> `B = sortrows(A,column)` sorts `A` based on the columns specified in the vector `column`. For example, `sortrows(A,4)` sorts the rows of `A` in ascending order based on the elements in the fourth column

```
dataset1 = [0
32
45
8];

dataset2 = [5
12
27
10];

dataset1_index = [2
5
6
9];

dataset2_index = [3
7
8
13];

tmp = sortrows([dataset1_index dataset1; dataset2_index dataset2], 1);

%    2    0
%    3    5
%    5   32
%    6   45
%    7   12
%    8   27
%    9    8
%   13   10


dataset3 = tmp(:, 2);
dataset3_index = tmp(:, 1);
```